# Import functions from a submodule into other submodule at the same directory level in Python

Tags: python, package, python-import

I am trying to make a package that has 2 subpackages. The directory structure looks like this:

```
project_folder
└── package_name
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── subpackage1
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── script1.py
    ├── subpackage2
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── script2.py
```

The `__init__.py` file in `package_name` is empty. The `__init__.py` in `subpackage1` looks like this:

```
from .subpackage1 import *
```

and let's say `script1.py` has this function:

```
def add(a, b):
   return a+b
```

Now `script2.py` in `subpackage2` has a collection of functions that may use some of the functions of `script1.py`. Let's say `script2.py` looks like this:

```
def add_extended(a, b):
   return add(a,b) + a
```

I have read many posts on StackOverflow, but so far I have not managed how to import a submodule that has dependencies on other submodules. I have tried to make `__init__.py` in `subpackage2` look like this:

```
from .subpackage2 import *
from ..subpackage1.script1 import add
```

In my mind, I am setting `subpackage2` in a way that when it is imported, the function `add` from `subpackage1` is also imported because `..` is looking for `subpackage1` in the parent directory. However, when I run a script like this:

```
from package_name.subpackage2 import add_1

a, b = 2, 4
add_extended(a,b)
```

It raises a `NameError: name 'add' is not defined`, so it pretty much is telling me that the function `add` from submodule `subpackage1` is not being imported properly when importing `subpackage2`.

I am using Python 3.8 on Windows 10.

**EDIT**

Interestingly, if I import the functions from `subpackage1` on `script2.py` itself instead of on `__init__.py`:

```
from ..subpackage1.script1 import add

def add_extended(a, b):
   return add(a,b) + a
```

the script below works:

```
from package_name.subpackage2 import add_1

a, b = 2, 4
add_extended(a,b)
```

However, I believe that is not how the package is supposed to work. Am I missing any file that should be added to enable me do what I want to do?

Comment: Have you tried `from ..subpackage1.script1 import add`?

Comment: @Axe319 yes I have tried and still does not work unfortunately. It is weird because if in a script I do ```from package_name.subpackage1 import add```, that function is imported as expected which makes me think the issue is with the way I set up the ```__init__.py``` in ```subpackage2```.

Comment: @Axe319 please see my edit on the original post.